# Is Fermi energy the same as chemical potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

In all of the textbooks, the [Fermi Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy) was interpreted as the energy level below which all possible energy states are filled. However with a Fermi-Dirac type of distribution, which has asymptotes at both edges why would there even be any such energy level which restricts energy levels higher than itself?, does then the idea of Fermi energy make sense only at zero temperature?

Also, there is a confusion between the idea of chemical potential and the Fermi energy at temperature other than zero.

Comment: The Fermi energy is the value that the chemical potential takes on at zero temperature. It does not itself depend on temperature.

Comment: You should look at 'The chemical potential of an ideal intrinsic semiconductor', Mark R. A. Shegelski, American Journal of Physics 72, 676 (2004); doi: 10.1119/1.1629090

Comment: "However with a Fermi-Dirac type of distribution, which has asymptotes at both edges why would there even be any such energy level which restricts energy levels higher than itself?" Under $T \rightarrow 0$ the distribution tends to *step function*

Comment: #Then Does the idea of Fermi Energy makes sense only at zero temperature ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the Fermi level and the Fermi-Dirac distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/549577/understanding-the-fermi-level-and-the-fermi-dirac-distribution)